# Compare line with next line in attribute table shapefile

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

I am making a python code for ArcGis 9.3. The aim is to compare the value of my field "ID_BV" at line l with value of field "ID_BV" at line l+ 1. And depending of the test answer i populate another field or not.

The problem look very simple : i don't know how can i acces to line l+1. I try to put twice :

rowNext = rows.Next()

rowNext = rows.Next()

With row my line and rowNext the next line.

But it doesn,t work. I also try a lot of other thing like that but it doesn't work.

The entire code is as follow :

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, glob
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Set a toolbox
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

MyShape = "C:\Users\marie.kremer\Desktop\Fabrication_Hydrogrammes\CalculMoyenne\\Test_Inter.shp"

gp.addfield (MyShape, "Moyenne", "double")

#Initialisation de variables
Somme = 3
#Position du curseur dans Mysghape
rows = gp.UpdateCursor(MyShape)
row = rows.Next()
rowNext = rows.Next()
rows.updateRow(rowNext)
rowNext = rows.Next()

gp.AddMessage(Somme)

while row:
    ID_BV = row.GetValue("ID_BV") 
    ID_BV_Next = rowNext.GetValue("ID_BV")

    gp.AddMessage("ID_BV")
    gp.AddMessage(ID_BV)
    gp.AddMessage("ID_BV_Next")
    gp.AddMessage(ID_BV_Next)

    if ID_BV == ID_BV_Next :

        gp.AddMessage("Entrée dans le IF")

        Somme = Somme + row.GetValue("AfoisF10p6") 

    else :

        gp.AddMessage("Entrée dans le Else")
        Somme = Somme + row.GetValue("AfoisF10p6") 
        row.SetValue("Moyenne", Somme)
        Somme = 2

    rows.updateRow(row)
    rows.updateRow(rowNext)
    rowNext = rows.Next()
    row = rows.Next()
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I changeg the second updateCursor by a searchCursor and it's work ! Thanks